# A m-dissipative operator is the generator of a $C_0$-semigroup

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $(H;(\cdot,\cdot))$ be a complex Hilbert space and let $A: D(A) \rightarrow H$ be a densely dened
closed operator on H. Let A be an m-dissipative operator that is
\begin{align}
&(Ax, x) \leq  0 \text{ for all } x \in D(A) \text{ and } \\
&\lambda I - A \text{ is surjective for every } \lambda  > 0.
\end{align}
Prove that $A$ is the innitesimal generator of a $C_0$-semigroup in $H$, that is, a semigroup $\{Q(t)\}$ satisfying the conditions of Denition 13.34(a)-(c) of Rudin's book.

Hint: show first that for each $\lambda > 0$ the operator $\lambda I - A$ has a bounded inverse with
norm $\leq \frac{1}{\lambda}$.

What I have done is the following:

Let $\lambda>0$ and $x\in\mathscr{D}(A)$. Then $\lambda I - A$ is surjective.
We show that $\lambda I - A$ is one-to-one so that $\lambda I - A$  is invertible.
Since $(Ax,x)\leq 0$ we have
$$
\lambda \|x\|^2 = (\lambda x,x) \leq ((\lambda I -A)x,x) \leq \|\lambda I -A\| \|x\|,
$$
so that
$$
\| (\lambda I - A)x \| \geq \lambda \|x\|. \tag{*}\label{*}
$$
Now $(\lambda I -A)x=0$ implies that $\|x\|=0$ and so by 12.1 $x=0$.
Hence $\mathscr{N}(\lambda I - T)=\{0\}$ and $\lambda I - A$ is one-to-one.

Let $y\in H$ then since $\lambda I - A$ is surjective we can find a $x\in\mathscr{D}(\lambda I -A)$ such that
$(\lambda I - A)x=y$. Then (\ref{*}) implies
$$
\|(\lambda I - A)^{-1}y\|=\|(\lambda I - A)^{-1}(\lambda I - A)x\|=\|x\| 
\leq \frac{1}{\lambda} \| (\lambda I - A)x \|= \frac{1}{\lambda}\|y\|
$$
thus
$$
\|(\lambda I - A)^{-1}\| \leq \frac{1}{\lambda}.
$$
Then for positive $m$, $C=1$ and $\gamma=0$ we have
$$
\|(\lambda I - A)^{-m}\| \leq \left(\frac{1}{\lambda}\right)^{-m}.
$$
So by theorem 13.37 $A$ is the infinitesimal generator of a $C_0$-semigroup.

The problem for me is that I haven't used the fact that the operator is closed.
So is the closeness unnecessary, or am I missing something?

Comment: Closedness of the generator is hidden in the boundedness of the resolvent. You did prove boundedness explicitely. This shows that the generator especially was closed as was to be expected.